# Is there any way to using variables in object name?

Tags: java, syntax

Let's say that we have a checkbox:

`JCheckBox lang_1 = new JCheckBox("English");`

In addition we have a variable that is binded to an ActionListener, so it is changing when ActionEvent occurs. This is the variable in the ActionEvent:

`(String) abbr = JComboBox<ComboItem> comboBox.getSelectedIndex().toString();`

Now, I have *abbr* equals *1* so i would like to `lang_1.setEnabled(true);`

**Is there any way to mix "lang_" with *abbr* to use as I would use lang_1 ?**

(In jQuery you could do this: `$("lang_"+abbr).doSomethingFunction();` )

Comment: you can do it with [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), but check the drawbacks section before adding this logic to product code.

Comment: I did not known about reflections, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to put your JCheckBoxes in an arraylist and call them with their index:

```
List<JCheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<JCheckBox> ();
boxes.add(new JCheckBox("English"));
// populate the list with the other check boxes

String abbr = JComboBox<ComboItem> comboBox.getSelectedIndex().toString();
int index = Integer.parseInt(abbr);
boxes.get(index).setEnabled(true);
```

You need to add the relevant error handling code on bounds, number parsing etc.

Comment: Simple to populate, simple to work with later.
Nice solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use reflection to do this.

The following example presumes you are having the code in the same class as the one having the combo box as a field.

```
  this.getClass().getField("lang_" + yourIndex).
     getMethod("setEnabled", new Class<?>[]{ boolean.class}).
     invoke(
         this.getClass().getField("lang_" + yourIndex).get(this), 
         new Object[] { true }
     );
```

I must admit it looks ugly :).

assylias's solution is much cleaner, self explanatory, and "syntactic", the latter being always a good way to approach things while in static-typed languages.

Comment: Firstly i tried yours but `getField()` does not have `getMethod()`  method. How could I obtain it properly ?

Comment: Finally I accepted the other suggestion but i liked this one very much! Thank you!